# React to R14 Heroku code by emptying memory cache

Tags: node.js, caching, heroku

My server sometimes receive R14 error codes because the memory limit has been reached. This is because I have a memory cache taking sometimes too much memory, and I would like to be able to react to R14 inside my nodeJS server, so that when I get this error code I delete least use entries of my cache.

Is it possible to listen to those codes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't listen to heroku errors from node.js, but whenever you update the cache, you can check [`process.memoryUsage()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage) and determine whether or not to prune the least-used values:

```
var { heapUsed, heapTotal } = process.memoryUsage();

// 90%, or some other limit you want to impose
if (heapUsed / heapTotal > 0.9) {
  // free some cache
}
```